# What strategies are critical to winning a Tetris DS tournament?

Tags: tetris, tetris-ds

In addition to basic *Tetris* play, what strategies are critical to winning *Tetris DS* in tournament play (items on, best two out of three)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In no particular order:

1. Ability to form T-Spin opportunities between (or instead of) Tetrises; this will let you keep a Back-to-Back chain going if need be
2. Remembering that you're in it to win it, not score big, so keep your stack at a maintainable level, usually below half the screen
3. Focus not only on finding great plays, but using garbage to your advantage; it's remarkably easy to turn a row of trash into a T-Spin Double opportunity
4. Keep your stack even and know when to go into emergency clearing mode. Avoid sharp towers like the plague because the banana peels will ruin your day.

Number 1 is important because if you can T-Spin fast, you can completely ignore Tetrises for garbage-sending.  It also helps for #3 when you need to clean up garbage; it's an easy way to get something back.

Two is important because a T-Spin Triple or Tetris back-to-back will send you up six or so rows, which can easily screw you over if you're already high up.

Other than that, just be fast and don't lose your cool.

Comment: Are back-to-back chains good? I always got irritated by them because they keep a straight empty column of garbage at the enemy screen, so they can throw an I there and Tetris. Of course, I'm not at tournament level, so my experience might be biased.

Comment: The garbage you send is, as far as I know, random. Sending a lot of small garbage has little to no effect.

Comment: Can you please explain what a T-Spin is, and how it's useful?

Comment: http://tetrisconcept.net/wiki/T-Spin is a good explanation, though it misses T-Spin Triples (something Tetris DS is 'famous' for). They are basically rewarded more than Tetrises (TSTriples are 1600xLV, Tetrises are 800xLV) and send more garbage, while only taking two or three lines to complete instead of four (less pieces = faster setup and execution = more garbage over time).